# For loop doesn't work in function called in Display function OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to draw a Spherical Cap with cyclinders.I am calling that function from my Display function.(Display function is my glutDisplayFunc) It seems the loop inside drawSphericalCap() doesn't work appropriately. It only loops once when i =0. I thought maybe I cannot loop outside of the display function. So that I copied the same code inside the display function. It didn't work also.

```
void drawSphericalCap(float shpereRadius, float maxRadius)
{
    float r = shpereRadius;
    float a = maxRadius;
    float h = r - sqrt((r * r) - (a * a));
    //teta + 2 * beta = 180
    float teta = asin(a / r);
    float tanBeta = tan((180 - teta) / 2);
    float numberOfCylinders = a * 10;
    float heightOfEachCylinder = h / (10 * a);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    int i = 0;
    for (i ; i < numberOfCylinders ; i++){
        cout << i;
        float translateOfEachCylinder =  r - h + (heightOfEachCylinder * i);
        glPushMatrix();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslatef(0, translateOfEachCylinder, 0);
        glRotatef(90,1.0,0,0);
        glutWireCylinder(a, heightOfEachCylinder, 50, 50);
        glPopMatrix();
        h = h - heightOfEachCylinder;
        a = h * tanBeta;
    }
}
```

in display function:

```
glPushMatrix();
drawSphericalCap(5,3);
glPopMatrix();
```

I couldn't find the code of Spherical cap so I looked at the formula and I think the code above would do the job.. when I find the problem ofcourse..

Comment: How are you determining that the loop only executes once? You're not flushing stdout, so your tracing output is unreliable. (Use `cout << i << endl;`, or `cout.flush();`, or write to `cerr` instead.)

Comment: `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);` seems fishy. Either the call is unnecessary because you already are in MODELVIEW mode, or you change which stack you are pushing/popping from in mid-function.

Comment: @molbdnilo Output is reliable, I have tried your recommendation, nothing changed.

Comment: @klas-lindbäck I am gettin only 1 cyclinder (with the biggest radius) on first loop, I have tried deleting the glMatrixMode line. Nothing changed also..

Comment: Remember that angles are in radians,  not degrees.

Comment: What's the value of `numberOfCylinders` when you reach the loop?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for warning that was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for tips..
tan function takes radians not degrees.
And the problem with the loop is related to tan function.(it returns negative so loop ends after first iteration).
I tried gluCyclinder() instead of glutWireCyclinder() because I could arrange both top and bottom radiuses of cyclinders.
So I came up with a code that almost satisfies me but there are small things that needs to be corrected. But I won't make myself busy with it. So final SphericalCap() function is like this (CAPMULTIPLIER can be changed for better quality):

```
#define PI 3.14159265
#define CAPMULTIPLIER 10

void drawSphericalCap(float shpereRadius, float maxRadius)
{
    float r = shpereRadius;
    float a = maxRadius;
    float h = r - sqrt((r * r) - (a * a));
    //teta + 2 * beta = 180
    float teta = asin(a / r);
    float tanBeta = tan((PI - teta) / 2);
    float numberOfCylinders = a * CAPMULTIPLIER;
    float heightOfEachCylinder = h / (10 * a);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    int i = 0;
    GLUquadricObj *cyclinder;
    cyclinder = gluNewQuadric();
    for (i; i < numberOfCylinders; i++){
        //cout << "i="<<i<< "  height="<<heightOfEachCylinder<<endl;
        float translateOfEachCylinder = r - h;
        float smallRadius = tanBeta * (h - heightOfEachCylinder) ;
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0, translateOfEachCylinder, 0);
        glRotatef(-90, 1.0, 0, 0);
        gluCylinder(cyclinder, a, smallRadius, heightOfEachCylinder , 50,5);
        glPopMatrix();
        h = h - heightOfEachCylinder;
        a = smallRadius;
        teta = asin(a / r);
        tanBeta = tan((PI - teta) / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The explanation does not make sense to me. The number of loop iterations (`numberOfCylinders`) is independent of the result of the `tan()` function. Am I missing something?